# ~/.ssh/config Is Being Ingored

Tags: git, wpengine

I'm trying to connect to Git at WPEngine.  I have created my config file, ensured I own it and permissions are set to 644.

When I run ssh I'm getting the following error, it seems that my machine is still trying to use another config.

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.wpengine.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to git.wpengine.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Jgp8bPftGbM0rzQaeA7KTBrZa1UfEN1nqQMLIwu5i18
debug1: Host 'git.wpengine.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:66kyWHTqkcoZFlueHMvyr/X20tF+5bk+KJ2+xUgxeE4
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/root/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:66kyWHTqkcoZFlueHMvyr/X20tF+5bk+KJ2+xUgxeE4
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@git.wpengine.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

My config file:

```
Host *.ssh.wpengine.net
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/wpengine_rsa
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssh traces indicate that it is scanning the `.ssh` directory of the `root` user (`/var/root/.ssh/*`). My guess is you are running a git command using `sudo ...`, so your command scans `root` ssh config -- not `your user` ssh config.

---

Run your git command using your regular user account.

Comment: Good catch. I did this and it does indeed use my config file now, but still not using the key I specified. id_rsa (which doesn't even exist) vs wpengine_rsa

Comment: `Authenticating to git.wpengine.com:22 as 'git'` : `git.wpengine.com` doesn't macth `*.ssh.wpengine.net`

Comment: If I specify the wpengine_rsa directly ssh -i ~/.ssh/wpengine_rsa git@git.wpengine.com info it connects just fine It's something about the config file.

Comment: Yes : `git.wpengine.net` does not match the pattern in your ssh config. Fix your config.

Comment: Ah yes I see that! I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `.ssh` directory should have the permissions set to `700`, and the `.ssh/config` file should have permissions set to `600`. OpenSSH will ignore them if the permissions are too open (no-one else should be looking at your ssh settings!)

Comment: I went ahead and made those changes, same error.